# Connecting JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This is a rather trivial question but I cannot seem to find a straight forward or helpful answer. I have created a simple web page which contains five image placeholders that are to be filled with one of nine random pictures. I have created (what I believe to be) a random picture generator using JavaScript. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to include the script (as a separate file) in the HTML document so that when the page loads, the script executes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="="text/javascript" src="mpl.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="mplstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Monroe Public Library</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pageContent">
        <div id="head">
            <img src="mpl.jpg" alt="Monroe Public Library" />
      </div>

        <div id="links">
            <ul class = "nav">
            <span>Quick Links</span>
            <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Online Catalog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends of MPL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Books and Other Good Reading</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ohio Virtual Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Public Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services and Collection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adult Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teen Central</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Children's Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computers at MPL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computer Rules and Procedures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library Records</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
        <h2>Library Records</h2>
            <p>To view the library records, enter your username and password.</p>

            <form id="login" method="post" action="">
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="center" id="input"> Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="center" id="input"> Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="captcha" id="input">As a final security check, enter the 5 numbers you see displayed below.</label>
                    <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" size="6" />
              </p>
              <p id="login">&nbsp;</p>
                <p align="center"><img src="" alt="" name="number1" width="70" height="100" id="number1"><img src="" alt="" name="number2" width="70" height="100" id="number2"><img src="" alt="" name="number3" width="70" height="100" id="number3"><img src="" alt="" name="number4" width="70" height="100" id="number4"><img src="" alt="" name="number5" width="70" height="100" id="number5"></p>
                <div id="images">
  </div>
                <p align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="View Library Records" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="address">
            <span class="addressBold">Monroe Public Library</span>
            580 Main Street, Monroe, OH &nbsp;&nbsp;45050
            <span class="addressBold">Phone</span>(513) 555-0211
            <span class="addressBold">Fax</span>(513) 555-0241
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



window.onload = function ()
{
    function randomPictures()
    {          //http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Random-Image-Script.phtml
        var pictureNumbers=new Array()
        //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
        pictureNumbers[1]="0.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[2]="1.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[3]="2.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[4]="3.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[5]="4.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[6]="5.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[7]="6.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[8]="7.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[9]="8.jpg"
        pictureNumbers[10]="9.jpg"

        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*pictureNumbers.length)

        if (randomNumber==0)
        {
            randomNumber=1
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==1)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==2)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==3)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==4)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==5)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==6)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==7)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==8)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
        if (randomNumber==9)
        {
            document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of all the `if` statements? Every single one of them executes the same statement!

Comment: *"The problem is that I cannot figure out how to include the script (as a separate file) in the HTML document [...]"* I recommend to have a look at http://quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: Remove **type="="text/javascript"** from the script tag!

Comment: Put your js code inside a file named `myscripts.js` and add this inside the `header` tag `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Comment: And yeah, have a close look at `type="="text/javascript"`. Do you notice anything strange?

Comment: The `<script>` tags belong somewhere inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags, not before the `<html>` element.

Comment: lotta weird stuff going on. what calls `randomPictures()`? it's easy t go wrong using `document.write` in an onload handler. are you sure that's intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `script` tag after **type** and you have to remove **type** when importing a `.js` file. and it should be imported the ***`head`*** zone.

Try this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="mplstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Monroe Public Library</title>
    <script src="mpl.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Something interesting is happening. Now it runs the script when the page loads. I can tell it is doing so because when I load the page I get one of the pictures in the top left corner of the screen and nothing else. If I refresh the page I get a different random number. So obviously the script is working, but it is not being integrated into the existing web page as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot figure out how to include the script (as a separate file) in the HTML document so that when the page loads, the script executes.

Use a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute.

```
<script src="/static/rotateImate.js"></script>
```

When the page loads, it will also load the script and run it.

Comment: don't forget that it should be in the <head> tag

Comment: why should it be in the <head> tag?

Comment: @deweyredman that's wrong, your script tag doesn't have to be in the head. In fact, it's pretty common to have it in the very end of the body tag so the html is loaded before the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a simple plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uP9v8zkYVzzBpU0IHFIf?p=preview).

Here is the import:

```
<script src="script.js">

</script>
```

Here is the function:

```
  window.onload = function(){
    alert('hello');
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `window.onload = function() { ... };`?

Comment: Nothing, check out the example that imports a script then executes a function onload.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<script>` tag with the source to the location of your saved JS file for example

```
    <script src="C://me/documents/example.js">
    window.onload = function ()
    {
    function randomPictures()
    {          //http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Random-Image-Script.phtml
    var pictureNumbers=new Array()
    //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
    pictureNumbers[1]="0.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[2]="1.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[3]="2.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[4]="3.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[5]="4.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[6]="5.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[7]="6.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[8]="7.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[9]="8.jpg"
    pictureNumbers[10]="9.jpg"

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*pictureNumbers.length)

    if (randomNumber==0)
    {
        randomNumber=1
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==1)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==2)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==3)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==4)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==5)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==6)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==7)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==8)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
    if (randomNumber==9)
    {
        document.write('<img src="'+pictureNumbers[randomNumber]+'" border=0>')
    }
}
```

}

If the JS file is in the same folder as your webpage, then you can simply just do

```
    <script src=example.js">
```